# Case sensitive search is not working for Remote Data (Odata)

Tags: javascript, jquery, rest, odata

I need to fetch case sensitive records from OData Service.

For this requirement, i have formed the filter string as follows

```
filter=startswith(ContactName,'a')
```

So, finally OData query will be

```
http://mvc.syncfusion.com/Services/Northwnd.svc/Suppliers?$select=SupplierID,ContactName&$filter=startswith(ContactName,'a')&$orderby=ContactName
```

Suppliers ODATA service has the following field

```
Supplier {
SupplierID
CompanyName
ContactName
ContactTitle
Address
City
Region
PostalCode
Country
Phone
Fax
}
```

The result is in-case sensitivity

> my requirements is, i need to fetch the data which has "small "a"
>   as starting letter"

But, it showed both "small a" and "capital A" records.

Where i commit the mistake and is there any other possibilities to achieve my requirements.

Comment: Hi Satpal, Suppliers is OData service. I have modified my query with Suppliers fields.

Comment: seems like some configuration missing.. http://services.odata.org/V4/OData/%28S%282jg0jzkrehhsuwbxo1slfevk%29%29/OData.svc/Products?$filter=startswith(Name,%27m%27) return no result it's working correctly with case sensitive. http://services.odata.org/V4/OData/%28S%282jg0jzkrehhsuwbxo1slfevk%29%29/OData.svc/Products?$filter=startswith(Name,%27M%27)  return result

Comment: Hi Balaji, I cannot able to understand your response. How will you form the filter string. Please highlight it. I am working on Odata not in the Odata V4 version.

Comment: check it the url link, you will find

Comment: Yes i have referred the URL link. Can you please check with your suggestion to the below URL link.http://mvc.syncfusion.com/Services/Northwnd.svc/Suppliers?$select=SupplierID,ContactName&$filter=startswith(ContactName,'a')

Comment: yeah correct, yours not working. I already mentioned seems like some configuration missing and not sure about this.

Comment: Hi Balaji, Could you please tell what configuration am i missing in my code snippet.